# Error with authentication in Spring sercurity

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc

I have created a form for a user and admin login to a web app in Spring MVC
and I have the following config file in Spring MVC:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="admin1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>



    <!-- authentication from database -->
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password from [Simplehr].[dbo].[USERS] where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="Select username, concat('ROLE_',user_role) user_role from user_roles where username=?" />
    </authentication-provider>

</authentication-manager>
```

But when I run the app, I see an error for a failed Login:

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password
>   from [Simplehr].[dbo].[USERS] where username=?]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index 3.

But when I run the SQL statement in SQLserver it works.

Comment: You might want to post an example of your table so we can see what is going on. On another note, you might want to investigate into SQL injection attacks, as I believe you are going to be very prone to them with this current code!

Comment: Your `users-by-username-query` is wrong. The result must contain 3 columns no more no less. the first is username, second password and third is enabled .

Comment: select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?.right @M.denium.It still wrong